# Does `instanceof` operator violate Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

For example I have `Currency`, and `Exchange` which deals with various implementations of `Currency`.  I want to have an extra rate for curtain currencies, I do it like so

```java
interface Currency { double rate();}
interface Exchange { double convert(Currency currency, double money); }
class PrivateBank implements Exchange {
    @Override
    public double convert(Currency currency, double money) {
        double extra_rate = 1.0;
        if (currency instanceof CanadaDollar) { /// ?
            extra_rate = 1.05;
        }
        return money * currency.rate() * extra_rate;
    }
}
```

Is LSP violated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The Liskov Substitution Principle is about subtypes faithfully exhibiting all the properties of their supertypes.  In no way does it forbid other code from handing different subtypes of the same type differently.

Your example code *is* a bit smelly, but not because of any conflict with the LSP.

Answer (score 1):

No, because any implementation of `Currency` can be passed in to `convert` and a result will be returned.

Comment: But the logic for Canadian dollars are coupled with `CanadaDollar` class. What if I add another implementation which happens to be also CAD? There is no way for me to tell `PrivateBank` to handle my new implementation in the same manner.

Comment: If `CanadaDollar` is an implementation of `Currency` then it does not violate LSP, but yes you would have to update `PrivateBank` with any new currencies, or rate changes. A better solution would be to abstract out `extra_rate` into the `Currency` so that each currency is responsible for its respective rate.

Answer (score 0):

The above is called "potential violation of LSP" . Any instance check to identify the subtype of a Supertype is  considered as a potential violation.

The implementation should not differ for different subtypes. In your case there is no conflict other than just a different value. But still this can be fixed by having a function or value to return exchange rate rather than checking the subtype and setting it.